# Tracking form abandonment

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, tracking, forms

I'm looking for a decent way to track form abandonment. Ideally, I would like to see how many people start filling out a form but do not complete it, as well as the last field that was filled out.

The website is a fairly large Wordpress site with quite a few forms. Some of these forms are to register for events, some are for donations, some are for information requests.

My first attempt at this was adding a generic jquery that bound functions to all forms on the site. When a form element was blurred, I would trigger a Google Analytics event with the name of the form, the name of the field, and whether or not it was filled. I expected to be able to go to the Event Flow section in Google Analytics and see the flow of these form events, however since there are so many forms and other events occurring on the website, Google wouldn't let me break them out very well. The other issue was the Quform doesn't name their fields anything relevant, and it doesn't look like we can name them ourselves. This results in a lot of ugly form names that don't mean anything without cross-referencing the actual form.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can achieve more usable form abandonment metrics in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best way to handle this is to use Ajax to send each field back to the server when it loses focus. Save it in your tables were you normally would but add one more field to each table for a completed status. This will give you the data needed to analyze yourself.

This does seem like an odd metric to bother tracking.